# Embedded Google maps place location lat long stopped working

Tags: google-maps

I have a Web App that has an embedded Google map using GPS lat long coordinates. It has been working for years but recently stopped and now just displays the entire world. The section of the source is:

```
<iframe width="100%"
height="200"
frameborder="0" style="border: 0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=API_KEY&q=loc:52.123456+0.234567">
```

According to the Google documentation it is not possible to use the 'place' mode with lat long. I can use the 'view' mode but this does not give me the place marker.

What I find odd is that I can use the same format in a url and it all works.

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=loc:52.123456+0.234567
```

This gives me the map with a place marker that I used to get embedded in my page.

Any ideas what has changed?

Comment: I don't see `loc:` [documented in the embed API](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#place_mode), where did that come from?

Comment: I inherited the use of loc: from the original code developer. It used to work OK and still works when used in a query string but not when I try and embed a map